# How to get the maximum value of a field by some conditions in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am new to mongodb, I am trying to write a query for finding max salary by department equal to IT.How can i write the query in mongobd i know how to write this query in oracle but i am unable to write query in mongodb.I have check other question on stack overflow but not found any related to my question.If someone knows please guide me.Thank you.
 my collection:

```
{
"salary" : "1000",
"department" : "IT"
}
{
"salary" : "2000",
"department" : "IT"
}
{
"salary" : "3000",
"department" : "IT"
}
```

expected out put:

```
{
"salary" : "3000"
}
```

i know this is very silly question but i am new here for mongodb.

Comment: refer the mongo db $max aggregation link below, it provides exactly what you need.. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/

Answer (score 1):

```
Query query = new Query();
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "salary"));
query.limit(1);
QueryObject maxObject = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, QueryObject.class);
```

Comment: if i want to run this query in roboMongo then how should write this?